# Is the rules event "Before saving a user account" applied every time a user edits their account?

Tags: users, rules

I would like to apply a rule that allows existing users whose email addresses come from a certain domain to continue using their existing accounts, but to prevent the creation of future accounts from these domains.

I have configured my rule to react on the ***After saving a new user account*** event, but I'm unsure as to whether to have it react also on ***Before saving a user account.***

Does *saving* here refer to only to account creation, or also to account updates such as a password change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Before saving a user account*** will react before you make a change in the user account.

And ***After saving a new user account*** will react After you create the user account.

But if you have the 2 events once you create a new user account you will trigger first the ***Before saving a user account*** event and after the ***After saving a new user account*** event.

If you go to create or update a user account always you need to call the [user_save()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_save/7.x) function. The difference is in the first param. See this question with an example:

[Create a user programmatically and give they a role](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/6976/28275)

Comment: Are you familiar with the [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/137500/how-to-troubleshoot-rules-when-a-required-variable-for-an-event-is-not-provided/201548#201548)? Reason why I ask: the kind of questions like this one here, are not obvious to answer ... My recommendation would be "***time to turn on Rules debugging ... in your own site ... to find the real answer by asking the rules module to tell you what it's doing ...***"

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I agree with you

Comment: So for the _Before saving a user account rule_ to apply, there must be an existing using account? Does it also apply to newly created accounts?

Comment: @Tadhg Yes apply to the newly accounts because when you go to create and update a user account always you need to use the user_save(), see my edit for more information.

Comment: Hey Adrian, I noticed the URL you include ends with "q/6976/28275": the "q/6976"-part of it is clearly the question ID. But what's the purpose of that "28275" in it? As far as I can see, if you'd change it to just "q/6976" you end up at the very same spot in the linked question. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens the number 28275 is my user number, when you click in the share link in the question you will see your number at the end, you can use this link yo have access to the Announcer, Booster and Publicist badges

Comment: Aha, now that is interesting! Never knew about that, and even never understood those bizarre badges ... Merci for teaching me about it ... PS: wanna try [this link](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/221032/39516) ???